# Programmatically setting an Animator value

Tags: android, animator

I am trying to add an animation on android. I got a vector drawable with a path, and an animator in xml

```
<objectAnimator
    android:name="fillCircleAnimator"
    android:propertyName="trimPathStart"
    android:duration="800"
    android:valueFrom="1"
    android:valueTo="0.2"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:repeatCount="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
/>
```

Now, I would like to change the `valueTo` parameter dynamically, so something like

```
fun animNow() {
    val animated = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(context, 
    R.drawable.my_animated_drawable)

    myImageView.setImageDrawable(animated)
    animated.setToValue(someValue) // This function doesn't exist
    animated?.start()
}
```

How can I achieve that?

**Edit**

As you can see in the code above, the goal is to animate `trimPathStart`. I asked a more generic question, but the answer I really need is specifically for `trimPathStart`

Comment: `set*Values()` ?

Comment: @pskink The goal is to edit `trimPathStart` but `setTrimPathStart` doesn't exist